Matlab gives the error "Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type" in only one of two identical lines
I have a list box of countries in my app where you can select a country. The countries are read from a data table that where some of them are repeated multiple times for each specific state contained in a different column of the table. My code is supposed to check if the country has a state and if it does record it in the list box only if it is the first time a state of the specific country. To do this I have the following code in the startup function, but MATLAB is throwing the error "Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type" for the line:
app.CountriesListBox.Items{ii-1} = names_of_countries{ii-1}{1}

, but only for the second version of this line that is contained within the second if loop. Any ideas? Here is the code:
for ii = 2 : num_rows 
                if isempty(app.Data{ii, 2})
                    names_of_countries{ii - 1}{1} = app.Data{ii, 1};
                    app.CountriesListBox.Items{ii-1} = names_of_countries{ii-1}{1};
                else
                    if k == 0 && ~isempty(app.Data{ii + 1, 2})
                        app.CountriesListBox.Items{ii-1} = names_of_countries{ii-1}{1}; 
                    elseif k == 1 && isempty(app.Data{ii + 1, 2})
                        k = 0;
                    else
                        continue;
                    end
                end
end


Please see [mcve] and then [edit] your question accordingly

Just because the lines of code are the same, it does not mean they will give the same behaviour. Immediately before the first time you call that line, you define what names_of_countries{ii-1}{1} is equal to. In the 2nd case you don't, so what is it meant to be defined as? Have you added a breakpoint there to see if that variable is what you expect it to be? I suspect it's at least not a cell, owing to that error message
